# In R, I'm having trouble using the Regex operators to pull out numerous strings of a year type (2019 to 1999) and character type (Week1 to Week16)

Tags: r, regex

So specifically, I have a data frame with roughly 6 million records pulled from numerous .csv files from multiple folder locations.  The row names of my data frame are the folder location name and take the following form:

file_names
//Users/me/Desktop/R Scripts/Fantasy Football Model/FantasyPros Fantasy Football Weekly Data 1999 - 2019/**2019**/**week1**.csv.1

I want to be able to pull out the bold in the above so that I can categorize each elements year and week but note that the week will range from week1 to week16 and year will range between 1999 and 2019.  I can do this easily if the strings I need were always at the same string position but not sure how to parameterize the regex operators.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two regex's, one for each string to extract.

```
year <- sub(".*/(\\d+)/.*$", "\\1", x)
year
#[1] "2019"

week <- sub(".*/([^/\\.]+)[\\.].*$", "\\1", x)
#[1] "week1"
```

**Data**

```
x <- "file_names //Users/me/Desktop/R Scripts/Fantasy Football Model/FantasyPros Fantasy Football Weekly Data 1999 - 2019/2019/week1.csv.1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  Took me while to understand and had to tinker a little with it for what I needed but finally got this issue solved in my script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the year will always occur within `/` and that the week always has literal `week` in it:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=/)\\d+(?=/)")
[1] "2019"

str_extract(x, "(?<=/)week\\d+(?=/|\\.)")
[1] "week1"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `word` with `basename`

```
library(stringr)
word(basename(x), 1, sep="\\.")
#[1] "week1"
```

#### data

```
x <- "file_names //Users/me/Desktop/R Scripts/Fantasy Football Model/FantasyPros Fantasy Football Weekly Data 1999 - 2019/2019/week1.csv.1"
```